# threading - shell stuck at program exit

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have written a network mapper based on `python-nmap` library.
I have a list which contains all IP addresses to scan.
From `htop` I see all threads spawned are terminated before the program exit.

When the program execution is finished, the shell (I use bash) stucks. When I write something it doesn't display me what I am writing. If I write 'reset' (even if I can't see it), the shell is correctly reinitialized.

What is wrong?

I run the script using Python 3.7.3 installed on a Debian 10 Buster distro.

Below is the piece of code.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

hosts_up = ['192.168.0.5', '192.168.0.6', '192.168.0.8']
fingerprinting_threads = []
nm_obj = nmap.PortScanner()

# Callback
def fingerprintAndSaveToDb(host_to_fingerprint):
    scan_result = nm_obj.scan(hosts=host_to_fingerprint, ports=None, arguments=' -sN -Pn')
    print(scan_result)

# Main flow
for single_host_up in hosts_up:
    t = threading.Thread(target=fingerprintAndSaveToDb, args=(single_host_up,))
    t.start()
    fingerprinting_threads.append(t)

print("Joining")
for single_thread in fingerprinting_threads:
    single_thread.join()
print("Joint")

# sys.exit() - It could be unuseful
```

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use no threads, i.e. just call `fingerprintAndSaveToDb` directly?

Comment: Python doesn't do that by itself, it sounds like something being done by the nmap library.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No problem occurs when I run it with no threads.

Comment: Have you considered **not sharing** `nm_obj` across all the threads, in case it contains internal state?  eg each thread should have its **own** `nm_obj`

Comment: @donkopotamus I have just tried, the problem still occurs. The first operation of `fingerprintAndSaveToDb()` is  now `nm_obj = nmap.PortScanner()`.

Comment: The problem occurs with `python3-nmap` library too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the shell from `bash` to `zsh` the problem has gone.